# How to get script that processes names and links inside a dynamix website

Tags: url, flutter

I am using several apis to create an anime application. This application has several features. One of them is that it allows you to download anime eps. There is currently no api that allows you to take anime download links so I am scraping gogoanime.io for download links. The problem is that gogoanime does not have a proper naming convention in its url schema. I am fetching the anime name from myanimelist jikan api and using the name plus combination of the baseurl I generate the url in gogoanime.  But sometimes gogoanime does not go with the conventional naming. For example an anime called " Strike the Blood", its url will be gogoanime..../strike-blood. So how to deal with this naming difference. What are the proper ways to access the URLs of gogoanime? By the way I am using flutter snd beautifulsoup to scrape.